# 3D Effect to buttons in java swing using nimbus

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, nimbus

[image]I have used Nimbus to create rounded corners for buttons in swing referring here:
[Use Nimbus to give rounded corners for JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143648/use-nimbus-to-give-rounded-corners-for-jbutton/22143941?noredirect=1#comment33617392_22143941)

I now want to give a 3d look to the buttons. How should I go about this using nimbus?
i had gone through nimbus but coudnt find appropriate info

note: I have added image where button1 shows that I have used:
 generateButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

and second with nimbus effect

Comment: Define "3D effect" - You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233928/how-to-set-a-3d-border-for-a-jdialog-with-rounded-corners/12234240#12234240) perhaps?

Comment: @MadProgrammer:
I have a button like:
JButton generateButton = new JButton("<html><b>button1</b></html>");
        generateButton.setActionCommand("generate");

For this I have applied NImbus mentioned in the link in my question. So now how do I relate it to the link you provided. I am not able to do it

Comment: How is the default button not "3D"?

Comment: I did not understand your ques

Comment: How is the current `JButton` under Nimbus not "3D", it looks "3D" to me?

Comment: @MadProgrammer:
I used
generateButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
but its kinda overlapping with the curved edges done using nimbus and not giving a proper image

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I have updated my ques with the image

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a suggestion than an answer.

From looking at your previous questions it seems this button has been a problem for you. It seems your initial question regarding the button didn't include using `Nimbus` *at all* but was more just how to get the button look and functionality.

I might suggest instead of trying to mess with the look and feel, maybe just pick a look and feel that is to your liking. All of the one below can be found at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net)

**SeaGlass LAF**

[image]

**Liquid LAF**

[image]

### JTattoo library has assorted LAFs you can choose from

**JTattoo Acryl LAF**

[image]

**JTattoo Graphite LAF**

[image]

**JTatto McWin LAF**

[image]

**JTatto Texture LAF**

[image]

### Happy Searching!